# Suggest Users basing on User taxonomy

Tags: functions, taxonomy, users

My question is for getting informations or directions about how to move for a task I have to do. This is just a request for advices due to the fact I'm not an expert in wordpress development.

My task would be to create a module (widget or just a query) which suggests registered users based on categories they've subscribed (user taxonomy like *profession*), just after somebody else post something.

I'll do an example:

1. I post a job (form) selecting which profession it'd be dedicated for (user taxonomy);
2. After the confirmation I get a widget showing 3 suggested users, matching the profession (user taxonomy) I've selected while posting.

I've created the user taxonomy but I don't really know where to start for this task. Do you know any article or question talking about something like it?
Can you drive me to what I should study for it?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you add user taxonomy? Problem with user taxonomies is that there's no native support and you can't use it in user query! I suggest to use user meta instead and then you could use [`WP_User_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query). Read it (_there are plenty of examples on that page_), try it and get back to us if it didn't work out. :-)

Comment: I've followed some tutorial for creating it like [this one](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress). So do you think I should work with user meta instead? Thanks @TwerkingN00b

Comment: And working with user meta how could I manage it from my dashboard? @TwerkingN00b

Comment: Do you have access to your database? I need to know how this taxonomy is linked to user. Does users table has a new column? Is there a new table called `wp_user_relationships` for example or is this relationship saved as user meta in `wp_usermeta` table.. Please add a taxonomy to one of your users and check it out. Then I can help you further.

Comment: I have access to my database and I see that these categories are added to `wp_terms` table. More specifically I've followed exactly [this tutorial](http://www.innovext.com/au/wordpree-user-category/). @TwerkingN00b

Comment: Then I assume that relatonship is saved to `wp_term_relationships` table. In that case we have a problem because users can't be queried by taxonomies. Im writing an answer to your question, it will be ready in few minutes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query users by taxonomy. You will need to rethink your system. What would I do?

- Keep the taxonomies but use these only to output choosable values - [wp_dropdown_categories()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)
- Save the selected value **AS** user meta, **NOT AS** taxonomies - [update_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)
- Now you can query users by that value - [WP_User_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

---

**Example:**

This code would go to the page template where your jobs are posted.

```
// This will check if form was submitted, it will not trigger/show on "normal" page load
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

    // This will get the profession from input after form is submitted & page reloaded
    // Change "profession" to the name of that input where user can choose profession
    $submitted_profession = $_POST['profession'];

    // Arguments for user query, see more from the user query link above
    $args = array(

        // How many to return?
        'number' => 3,   

        // User meta
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'profession',  // Name of user meta key in database
                'value'   => $submitted_profession, // We get this from form, see above
                'compare' => '=' 
            )
        )
    );

    // Query itself
    $suggested_users_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    // Get the results
    $users = $suggested_users_query->get_results();

    // Check if there actually are users based on that criteria 
    if ( ! empty( $users ) ) {

        // All the output how you want your users to look like goes here 

        // I wrote a small example

        echo '<ul>';

        // Loop trough each user 
        foreach ( $users as $user ) {

            // Get all the user data
            // To find all the fields you could use, search "get_userdata()" online
            $user_info = get_userdata( $user->ID );
            echo '<li>' . $user_info->first_name.' ' . $user_info->last_name . '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';

    } 
    // No users with that profession
    else {

        echo 'No users with profession ' . $submitted_profession;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wooow! Thank you for your deep and useful support! Great!